# Invoice creation display 'Requested product does not exist' error

Tags: magento2

I have created a product after that place order. I remove that product and create a new product with the same SKU.

Now I create an invoice for that order it displays 'Requested product does not exist' error.

Can someone help me how can I resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Product SKU and Product Id both save in `sales_order_item` table.

As you created New Product with Same `SKU` but Product ID changed. You need to update `Product Id` with New Product Id in `sales_order_item` table.

Hope this help !!

Comment: Have change that still it's display same error.